# site layout messing up in IE only

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, dreamweaver

I have a site built in Dreamweaver using HTML and CSS.

The layout is exactly how I want it in all browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari) except for Internet Explorer 7 where the layout of the bottom row of images or image is totally messed up -  either too high or too much to the right. I have no idea why this is happening, I am a beginner and have tried all I can think of, if anyone can help that would be much appreciated.

The site is here: http://www.mediadarling.co.uk/clients/lenistudios/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure? It looks the same (and fine too) in IE8 and in Chrome.

Comment: please specify the version of IE that you're testing with.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @GolezTrol and @Spudley - the problem occurs with IE7 and I still have not managed to fix it.

Comment: did you try my suggestion of surrounding those elements by a div with the suggested styles?

Answer (score 1):

There’s a couple of bits in your CSS that I don’t quite understand:

```
#movers-row {
    ...
    margin: -120px 0 0 120px;
```

Why the negative top margin? This seems to be what’s pulling the images up too far in IE 7. I don’t really understand why it’s not in other browsers; something to do with the floats involved I guess.

```
#footer {
    ...
    margin-top: -130px;
```

Is this related to the other negative top margin?

Anyhoo, I think you can fix your issue in IE 7 by:

- Removing those two negative top margins
- Adding `margin-top: 10px;` to `#imagerow` just in IE 7 (and possibly IE 6) (the padding top doesn’t work with the floats for some mysterious IE reason)

See here for example code: http://www.pauldwaite.co.uk/test-pages/5220698/

You’ve also got a couple of validation errors in your HTML. I don’t think they’re causing your issue, but I fixed them first, because when you’re trying to track down an IE bug you really don’t want validation errors in there. [Here’s the validation of the page.](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.mediadarling.co.uk/clients/lenistudios/&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Comment: @Paul D. Waite, thanks for your suggestion, I tried both left and right but it didn't seem to change anything..?

Comment: @noobug: sure, sorry, worth a shot. I’ve had a proper look at the CSS now, I’ll edit my answer.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite thank u v much. I've tried to copy what u suggested but for me it still goes wrong in IE7. The movers row has those margins as I copied the technique from this tutorial: http://css-tricks.com/equidistant-objects-with-css/ I tried changing the margins but then the alignment went wrong. The negative top margin on the footer is because I want to 'lift' the footer image (water colour splashes) behind the image row, that's the way it was designed. If I remove the -margin it goes below the images. Any ideas how I can solve this / what I'm still doing wrong much appreciated! Thank u.

Comment: @noobug: ah, I see, that makes sense of the negative margins. I’ll take another look.

Comment: @noobug: have you still got the original version up anywhere? The stylesheet seems to be missing from your site.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite, thanks, I have re-uploaded it to http://www.mediadarling.co.uk/clients/lenistudios/

Comment: @noobug: yeah, I’m not really sure what’s going on. I don’t think the negative top margin on movers-row is required, that seems to be what’s pulling the images out of position in IE 7. When you remove it, the images seem to get hidden by the footer as it’s drawn up by its own negative margin. You can fix *that* by assigning `position: relative; z-index: 2;` to `imagerow`.

Comment: @noobug: I don’t think you need to use the equidistant objects CSS from that other site, as you’ve got a fixed width design: you can just float all the little images left, and apply different left margins to the first and second ones. I’ve done a rewrite demonstrating this here: http://www.pauldwaite.co.uk/test-pages/5220698/rewrite/. Sorry I can’t be more help, but you’ve got a lot of CSS going on there, it can be a bit difficult to see what’s doing what. E.g. `#main img {float: right;}` — do you *really* want all images inside `#main` floated right?

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your advice @Paul D. Waite. I do realise that the CSS is probably really messy - as I said I am just learning this. Cheers for pointing out about the #main img issue above - I didn't realise it was affecting so much and sorting that out has already helped me a lot. I have now done an IE7 specific style sheet and am starting to get there with the site (hopefully!) :)

Comment: @noobug: excellent, glad you’re making progress. Sorry we haven’t been more helpful — CSS is a bit subtle when you first start out. The simplest CSS rules tends to have the widest effects (e.g. `p {padding: 10px;}` puts padding on every `<p>` tag on your site) — as much as you can, try to write CSS rules that only apply to very specific parts of the page. Later on, you can spot duplication of code, and create new class names for code you’re re-using on a lot of HTML elements.

Comment: @noobug: you’re most welcome, best of luck with it. Come back to Stack Oveflow with any further questions.

Answer (score 0):

After: `<div id="rotxt">Roll over images to see larger versions</div>`
Place: `<p class="clear"><br /></p>`

The .clear contains the CSS: `clear: both;`

Comment: Moves it down a little, but doesn't fix it. I'm assuming he's talking about IE7, where it's broken.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @SiteSafeNL, but as @thirtydot points out it only moves it down but doesn't fix the problem. Yes I am testing with IE7.

Answer (score 0):

you can use conditional statements for IE, here's an example:

```
<!--[if IE 7]><link href="css/layoutIE7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><![endif]-->
```

This is placed at the `<head>` and assumes that you have an extra css file with the IE corrections.

P.S. you need to add your IE specific CSS rules into the IE CSS file, that way it will work in IE and most browsers...

In my example, I used the "if IE 7", means if it is IE version 7, but you could use combinations and other versions.

EDIT: surround the Dear guest, text, image and the div #rotxt with another div and make sure it actually surrounds it with a simple rule:

`.surround {height: auto; overflow: hidden;}`

this is cross-browser, no need for the conditional CSS.

EDIT 2:
Ok, the problem here is in several places...
You're floating the image to the right, ok
I suggest surrounding the title + text + caption with a div with a float left.
Then surround both the image's div and the new div with an aditional div. This one with a height: auto and overflow: hidden.
Then remove the float of the images main div, and remove the top margin;
Finally, it would be best to add the orange rectangle as an element that comes after the images block (this way it's guaranteed that the social div comes in the right place).

So, my suggestion is something like this (sorry for not real tags):

[new surrounding div]
[main image div]
image
[/main image div]

[surrounding div]
title
text
caption
[/surrounding div]
[/new surrounding div]

[images div]
images
[/images div]

[sepatator div] (optional)
[/sepatator div]

[social div]
[/social div]

Comment: True, but what is he supposed to *put inside* this stylesheet?

Comment: Thanks a lot @jackJoe. I understand what you mean about attaching another stylesheet & putting a condition for IE7, but I don't understand what to do to the CSS in order to have the image row &  row of social media links in the right place. I have tried changing all the margins, padding, etc, but I cannot achieve the same layout in IE7 as it does in the other browsers. I also tried adding the additional div around the main text and images with a class "surround" applied to it, and the above CSS rule, and this caused the row of images to completely disappear and the social media links moved up.

Comment: nevermind the IE7 specific, just surround those elements with a div and set its styles to auto height and a hidden overflow, this way it will "force" the block to push the rest to the right place. Also, maybe it would be best to specify a height (or at least max-height) for that new div, this way it will guarantee that the base elements are always in place.

Comment: P.S. just re-read your comment, and are you sure you surrounded the right elements? as long as you have a specific height on the top div, the ones beneath will be placed correctly.

Comment: Thanks @jackJoe, I really appreciate the advice and I have tried surrounding the elements (from before <div id="main"> to after "rotxt"), and tried other combinations as well, but it is pushing the content below downwards and not moving the image row, or (when trying to wrap different elements inside) it hides the whole image row and still pushes up the social media links. So not sure which elements I should be surrounding but I've tried every logical place I can think of and unfortunately not getting anywhere with this... Thanks for your help.

Comment: that's because the image row is floated to the left, remove its float and follow my new edit.

Comment: Thank you @jackJoe - I have tried what you suggested to the best of my ability, but I am unable to achieve the layout again, in fact it all aligns differently now. For example when you say to remove the top margin of the main images div I'm confused, as I can't see any margin so I'm not sure which div you mean? Also are you saying to add two new divs or three? I'm sorry but I don't quite understand. :(